# PHP mouse over not working?

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have tried the following script in my joomla site to check if a file exists and if it does show a mouseover image.. if not show a different mouse over image. The initial image shows but the image fails to load on mouse over or mouse off. I have used the same image for this example..

```
    <?php
 $image_on = 'sr_act_i_2.png';
 $image_off = 'sr_act_i_1.png';
  $actionsloaded = 'location of file I will be checking';
if(file_exists($actionsloaded)) 
echo '<img src="/administrator/components/com_srshare/images2/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src=\''.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\''.$image_on.'\';"/>';
else
echo '<img src="/administrator/components/com_srshare/images2/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src=\''.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\''.$image_on.'\';"/>';
?>
```

Any ideas what is wrong with my mouse over code?

Comment: Check the path on hover

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your mouseover code ... your file paths are wrong.  Take a second ... look again ... you'll get it

Comment: Thanks got it. I forgot to add the path through the code

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the path through the whole code:

```
echo '<img src="/administrator/components/com_srshare/images2/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src=\''.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\''.$image_on.'\';"/>';
```

should have been:

```
echo '<img src="/administrator/components/com_srshare/images2/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src=\'/administrator/components/com_srshare/images2/'.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/administrator/components/com_srshare/images2/'.$image_on.'\';"/>';
```

Sometimes the obvious just can't be seen.